# How Can I return 1 else 0

Tags: python, python-3.x

**I have this function this function that return 1 if the sum of any two numbers in it equals another number in the list : **

```
def two_sum(numbers:list ,k:int) -> int:
    return (1 for x in numbers for y in numbers if x+y==k)
```

**now i want to return 0 if the sum of these numbers doesn't equal k , so i have tried this way**

```
def two_sum(numbers:list ,k:int) -> int:
    return (1 for x in numbers for y in numbers if x+y==k else 0)
```

**but i keep getting invalid syntax error . any help? **

Comment: My recommendation is that you start with the simplest possible way to do what you want, including not using list comprehension. Try to make it work. Once it works then step by step refactor it to be more "Pythonic" and using list comprehensions. Do this refactoring in as small steps as possible, testing in between.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to change the if to be at the beginning of the comprehension

```
def two_sum(numbers:list ,k:int) -> int:
    return (1 if x+y==k else 0 for x in numbers for y in numbers)
```

When you are using `if` at the end of the comprehension is just to check if to add the element to the result.
At the beginning of the comprehension is checking the element by the `if` statement and if the condition is True then it returns the value else it will return the `else` value.

Comment: well now i want to change 1 and 0 to True and False but it keeps returning True whether x+y equals k or not . i tried to to change use the bool function too but still the same                                                                                                 
 'return bool(1 if x+y==k else 0 for x in numbers for y in numbers)'

Comment: You can try `return (x+y==k for x in numbers for y in numbers)` that will return you the equality result False or True.